# What is the logic for determining language-specific Solr index field names

Tags: solr

I am writing some optimised search code which talks directly to Solr (uses HTTP requests and parses JSON responses). I am skipping the ContentSearch Sitecore API altogether. Some index fields are suffixed with _s of type string and shared (not specific versions per language). Some index fields are suffixed with _t of type text and are non-shared. When I browse the schema with the Solr admin tool, I see that the fields suffixed with _t have related fields e.g. where there is

```
__display_name_t
```

there are also corresponding fields

```
__display_name_t_en
__display_name_t_fr
__display_name_t_it
```

Can I simply take the Sitecore context language, e.g. en-GB take the first two characters "en" and then append them to the end of my field name (provided it has the _t suffix), or is the logic more complex than this?

Is there some good way to validate field names to avoid ending up with an invalid search query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at index configuration, you will find something similar to

```
<typeMatch 
  type="System.String" 
  typeName="text"
  fieldNameFormat="{0}_t"
  cultureFormat="_{1}"
  settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
```

That's line says that `text` is the only type which uses `cultureFormat` to create language specific versions of the fields in Solr documents.

When Sitecore adds documents to index or queries index, it checks that `cultureFormat` setting and uses it to include language information.

As far as I know, language information is generated using code similar to:

```
return 
  culture.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
    ? string.Empty 
    : culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```